# How to assign HTML element ID, through an Angular component, to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, angular

I found a JavaScript library and a function, I struggled, but did include this JavaScript function in my Angular application.

The JavaScript code prints takes in an object (**`myData`**: *two arrays of numbers*), and passes this data to a function, which draws two charts, each chart corresponds to one of the two arrays of numbers.

First thing I had to do is figure out how to include this JavaScript in my Angular project, which wasn't easy. And I'm even still not sure if it worked or not, because I haven't finished connecting everything together.

So here's the JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
      <!-- This page was last built at 2020-10-16 19:40 -->

      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <!-- Plotly.js -->
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">
</div>
<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv2">
</div>
<script>
myData = {
    "loss": [
        0.6437230565968681,
        .
        .
        .
        0.015016184188425541
    ],
    "accuracy": [
        0.6740923523902893,
        .
        .
        .
        0.9943200945854187
    ]
}
dataPlot(myData)
function dataPlot(myData){


function range(start, end) {
    var ans = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        ans.push(i);
    }
    return ans;
}

yLoss = myData['loss'];
yAccuracy = myData['accuracy'];

traceLoss = {
  type: 'scatter',
  x: range(yLoss.length>0?1:0,yLoss.length),
  y: yLoss,
  mode: 'lines',
  name: 'Red',
  line: {
    color: 'rgb(219, 64, 82)',
    width: 1
  }
};

traceAccuracy = {
  type: 'scatter',
  x: range(yAccuracy.length>0?1:0,yAccuracy.length),
  y: yAccuracy,
  mode: 'lines',
  name: 'Blue',
  line: {
    color: 'rgb(55, 128, 191)',
    width: 1
  }
};


var layoutLoss = {
  title: 'Model Binary Crossentropy Loss',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Epochs',
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Loss',
    showline: false
  }
// for static size
  ,width: 900,
  height: 500
};

var layoutAccuracy = {
  title: 'Model Training Data Accuracy',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Epochs',
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Accuracy',
    showline: false
  }
// for static size
  ,width: 900,
  height: 500
};
var dataLoss = [traceLoss];
var dataAccuracy = [traceAccuracy];
divs('myDiv','myDiv2')
function divs(div1, div2) {
    Plotly.newPlot(div1, dataLoss, layoutLoss);
    Plotly.newPlot(div2, dataAccuracy, layoutAccuracy);
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you copy that code to a .html file it'll work.

See at the bottom of the code this function:

```
function divs(div1, div2) {
    Plotly.newPlot(div1, dataLoss, layoutLoss);
    Plotly.newPlot(div2, dataAccuracy, layoutAccuracy);
}
```

This function takes div1 and div2 values, those are the IDs for the 2 divs containing the charts.

What I need is, first, to pass `myData` to the function, which is easy and doable, not a problem.
The problem is, how am I supposed to give the IDs of the divs to the JavaScript function, and have it know where those divs are to begin with?
I've been trying with @ViewChildren and ElementRef. But no success.

Here's my HTML template so far:

```
<div #divs *ngFor="let item of [1,2]" [id]="'myDiv-' + item">Div {{item}}+{{whatevs}}</div>
<button (click)="getDivs()">Get divs</button>
```

and the component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

declare var dataPlot: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-ml-model-data',
  templateUrl: './ml-model-data.component.html',
})
export class MlModelDataComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChildren("divs", { read: ElementRef }) divs!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  myData: any;
  constructor() { }

  getDivs(): void {
    // this.divs.forEach((div: ElementRef) => div.nativeElement);
       this.divs.forEach((div: ElementRef) => console.log(div.nativeElement.getAttribute('id'))); 
       // this^ gets the IDs for both divs, not each one individually.
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.myData = {
      "loss": [0.6437230565968681,
        .
        .
        .
        0.39040950554258685],
      "accuracy": [0.6740923523902893,
        .
        .
        .
        0.9943200945854187]
    }
    dataPlot(this.myData);
    dataPlot.divs();
  }
}
```

I feel like I've put myself in an untangleable mess, and feel like there must be

Comment: There is an angular package for plotly. https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @enno.void oh........ well wow thank you! the fact that my brain did not go that way...
I'll try it!